Sales Navigator comes under which LinkedIn Sales Navigator API?
I currently have an account with Sales Navigator. I am wondering where I should apply for this API, which is described in this article:
Microsoft Documentation
I have signed up for the LinkedIn Developer Page but didn't find the Sales Navigator API there.

This is a customer service-related question that you should be asking LinkedIn support. This site is for questions related to programming, not applying for access to or locating an off-site resource. You'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.
